# Facebook Videos API empty response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, httprequest

I have been trying to get a user's video list using the following graph API:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/user_id/videos?access_token=access_token

My response is empty all the time. It does not give me an error. I have given all permissions to test this out. But still the same. The result is:

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

Anybody knows why this is the case?

Comment: Did the user grant you user_videos permission? Are you using their access token?

Comment: Yes. I am using user_videos permission. Trying with the API Graph Explorer as well. Still nothing.

Comment: Do `/me/videos`

Comment: That works. But how do I get it from another user?

Comment: You have them login to your app. Grant your app user_videos permission. You get an access token for them. And then you request `/me/videos` with their access token

Comment: Also, it worked for my personal account. But when I got a new access token for another account, tried to access the videos on their account, its still returning empty

Comment: Did the other account login and grant user_videos to your app? Did you use their access token to call `/me/videos`?

Comment: Used their access token and called /me/videos. Do I need to clear the cache or cookies in that case?

Comment: Does that other account you tested with have a role in the app (admin/developer/tester)? If not, did you submit your app for review already?

Comment: @CBroe I created a new app for the other user. Still returning empty.

Comment: do I need to submit my app for review before I can access these information?

Comment: Why would you create a new app? // If the user does not have a role in the app, then yes, you need to submit for review before you can ask them for any permissions besides the three basic ones that don’t require review.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why I'm not getting any response. The usual /me returns my name and the Facebook ID. /me/videos returns empty as shown above.